# SQL table structure for storing books with translation

Tags: sql, postgresql, translation

I am trying to create a sql table structure to store multiple holy books / scriptures in my database. I came up with a basic structure, and needed some help figuring out if it can be improved in anyway, as I'm not very aware of SQL best practices. Any help will be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_text (
    col_text_id int,
    primary key (col_text_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_language (
    col_language_id int,
    col_display_name varchar(32) unique not null,
    col_short_name varchar(3) unique not null,
    primary key (col_language_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_translation (
    col_translation_id int,
    col_language_id int not null,
    col_text_id int not null,
    col_display_value text not null,
    primary key (col_translation_id),
    foreign key (col_language_id) references tbl_language (col_language_id),
    foreign key (col_text_id) references tbl_text (col_text_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_book (
    col_book_id int,
    col_title int not null,
    col_author int not null,
    primary key (col_book_id),
    foreign key (col_title) references tbl_text (col_text_id),
    foreign key (col_author) references tbl_text (col_text_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_chapter (
    col_chapter_id int,
    col_book_id int not null,
    col_name int not null,
    col_sequence int not null,
    primary key (col_chapter_id),
    foreign key (col_book_id) references tbl_book (col_book_id),
    foreign key (col_name) references tbl_text (col_text_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_paragraph (
    col_paragraph_id int,
    col_book_id int not null,
    col_chapter_id int,
    col_text int not null,
    primary key (col_paragraph_id),
    foreign key (col_book_id) references tbl_book (col_book_id),
    foreign key (col_chapter_id) references tbl_chapter (col_chapter_id),
    foreign key (col_text) references tbl_text(col_text_id)
);
```

Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow is for *questions*. Yours is purely a code review, which will hardly benefit the general public and is consequently off topic.

Comment: If you have some code (e.g. SQL queries) that operates on this structure,  consider presenting your work and its unit tests in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there.  Note that the table and index definitions alone aren't enough for a _code_ review, and CR doesn't do _design_ reviews without code!